# Jackson does not support ISO date format

Tags: java, json, date, jackson

Writing a web service which supports both Xml and JSON media types. Following ISO standard to support date format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX`.
To support this format in xml I have written a `DateAdapter` class which takes carecof marshaling and un-marshaling of date fields.
There is a CustomSerialization and Deserialization class for Json formats. It's implementation is almost similar to Adapter class. But it throws exception.

```
@Override
    public void serialize(Date aDate, JsonGenerator aJsonGenerator, SerializerProvider aSerializerProvider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
        String dateString = dateFormat.format(aDate);
        aJsonGenerator.writeString(dateString);
    }
```

**Exception:**

```
Illegal pattern character 'X'
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(SimpleDateFormat.java:768)
```

> Using jackson v2.2.1
>   Working Adapter implementation is exactly same.

```
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");

    @Override
    public String marshal(final Date v) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(v);
        return dateFormat.format(v);
    }

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(final String v) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(v);
        return dateFormat.parse(v);
    }
```

Comment: What about Z instead of XXX? or XXXX?

Comment: be sure that you review the api documentation for the version of java that you are actually using.

Comment: @JoopEggen You were right on. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav That does not explain the error message. Also, four `X` is not permitted.

Comment: Well `Z` does not solve the error completely. Date with `Z` looks like `2014-08-06T13:18:30.504-0400` but with `XXX` it looks like `2014-08-06T13:18:30.504-04:00`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Joop Eggen`'s comment fixed the issue. Simple Date Format from `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");` to `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The `SimpleDateFormat` pattern letter `X` was added in Java 7. You must be using a lower version JRE.

[Javadoc 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) versus [Javadoc 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Then how come `SimpleDateFormat` is working for `XmlAdapter` class which I am using for Xml responses.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav I don't think it is. That `XmlAdapter` is probably not used.

Comment: Sorry. But that is not the case. If I remove XmlAdapter, responses come in different format.

Comment: I have got the solution though.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Deserializer and use it as an @Annotation

public class TemporalDeserializerLocalDateTime extends JsonDeserializer {

```
@Override
public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationCtx)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
        String content = oc.readValue(jsonParser, String.class);
        return LocalDateTime.parse(content);
    }
}
```

public class PaymentResource {

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = TemporalDeserializerLocalDateTime.class)
    private LocalDateTime paymentDate;
}
```